# Skill de Alexa no conecta con MySql en Amazon Web Services en RDS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, aws, alexa

Tengo un problema en el desarrollo de una Skill de Alexa que requiere conectarse a una base de datos que tengo configurada en RDS de Amazon Web Services de MySql, a la cual puedo acceder desde MyWorkbench MySql y puedo operar perfectamente dentro de la misma, habiendo configurado en la seguridad de la misma que se pueda acceder desde cualquier Host, pero a la hora de utilizar el código de la Skill:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
              host: "host",
              user: "user",
              password: "pass",
              port: 3306
            });
connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  speakOutput = 'Connected';
});
```

Utilizando propiamente en cada Intent funciones asincronas y teniendo en el package.json :

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "ask-sdk-core": "^2.7.0",
    "ask-sdk-model": "^1.19.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.326.0",
    "mysql": "^2.5.4"
  }
}
```

Y tras haber mirado en varias referencias, creo que el error tiene que estar en la configuración de la base de datos, pero no entiendo porqué entonces puedo acceder con el programa local.